# React Scheduler data update issue

Tags: java, reactjs, scheduler, syncfusion

I am having a real deal that I can't get over with. I am using ScheduleComponent in ReactJS to create a calendar and some appointments.

Here is my component which uses a ScheduleComponent. I have no idea how can I update some data from my API.

```
const CalendarComponent = () => {

    const [schedules, setSchedules] = useState([]);

    const dataManager = new DataManager({
        url: `http://localhost:8080/schedule/calendar`,
        crudUrl: `http://localhost:8080/schedule/updateCalendar`,
        adaptor: new ODataV4Adaptor,
        crossDomain: true
    });
    return(
            <section className="adminSection">

                <ScheduleComponent width='100%' currentView='Month' eventSettings={{dataSource: dataManager}}>
                    <ViewsDirective>
                        <ViewDirective option='Day'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='Week'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='Month'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='Agenda'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='MonthAgenda'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='TimelineDay'/>
                        <ViewDirective option='TimelineMonth'/>

                    </ViewsDirective>
                    <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, MonthAgenda, TimelineViews, TimelineMonth]} />
                </ScheduleComponent>
           
            </section>
    );

};
export default CalendarComponent;
```

And there is my Java ScheduleResponse for getting apropriate data from database.

```
public record ScheduleResponse(
        @JsonProperty("StartTime") LocalDateTime startTime,
        @JsonProperty("EndTime") LocalDateTime endTime,
        @JsonProperty("Subject") String subject
) {
    public static ScheduleResponse fromSchedule(Schedule schedule){
        return new ScheduleResponse(
                schedule.getDateTimeFrom(),
                schedule.getDateTimeTo(),
                schedule.getSubject());
    }
}
```

I would like to know how can I refer to a single data from dataSource using this component, and I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you use addParams of Query to handle the filtering in server and for the same we have prepared a sample below.

Service: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Service-294388409
Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-param-front-end?file=index.js

In the above sample based on Subject field we have filtered the data from back end.

UG Link:  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/data-binding/#passing-additional-parameters-to-the-server

Client side code

```
 public onCheckBoxChange(): void {
    let predicate: any;
    const checkBoxes: CheckBox[] = [this.confirmObj];
    checkBoxes.forEach((checkBoxObj: CheckBox) => {
      if (checkBoxObj.checked) {
        predicate = predicate ? predicate + ',' + checkBoxObj.label : checkBoxObj.label;
      }
    });
    this.scheduleObj.eventSettings.query = new Query().addParams(
      'Subject',
      predicate ? predicate : ''
    );
  }
```

Server side code:

```
public JsonResult LoadData(Params param)  // Here we get the Start and End Date and based on that can filter the data and return to Scheduler
{
    DateTime start = param.StartDate;
    DateTime end = param.EndDate;
    var subject = param.Subject;
    var data = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(app => (app.StartTime >= start && app.StartTime <= end) || (app.RecurrenceRule != null && app.RecurrenceRule != "")).ToList();  // Here filtering the events based on the start and end date value.
          
    if (param.Subject != null)
    {
        // Filter data based on additional parameter
        data = db.ScheduleEventDatas.Where(app => (app.StartTime >= start && app.StartTime <= end && app.Subject == subject) || (app.RecurrenceRule != null && app.RecurrenceRule != "")).ToList();
    }
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public class Params
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```